# How to use \multidipole with parallel option?

Tags: pstricks, pst-circ

I want to draw `R1+R2` that is parallel to `R3+R4` using `\multidipole` and `parallel`. Unfortunately, I got an error. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=none](10,-5)
    \pnodes
        (1,-2){A}
        (8,-2){B}
    \multidipole(A)(B)
        \resistor{$R_1$}
        \resistor{$R_2$}.
    \multidipole[parallel](A)(B)
        \resistor{$R_3$}
        \resistor{$R_4$}.
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is on the (long) to-do-list ... :-(

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,1)(9,-3)
\pnodes(1,-2){A}(8,-2){B}(1.5,0){Aa}(7.5,0){Bb}
\multidipole(A)(B)\resistor{$R_1$}\resistor{$R_2$}.
\multidipole(Aa)(Bb)\resistor{$R_3$}\resistor{$R_4$}.
\pcline{*-}(Aa|A)(Aa)\pcline{*-}(Bb|B)(Bb)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]